# Equivalence of pointwise stabalizer and centralizer

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations, symmetric-groups

In *Finite Group Theory, 2nd Edition*, Aschbacher states

> For $Y \subseteq X$, I'll sometimes write $C_G(Y)$ ... for $G_Y$.... Usually this notation will be used only when $X$ possesses a group structure preserved by $G$.

Why is this notation justified? Are $C_G(Y)$ and $G_Y$ equivalent in some way or under certain situations?

### Notation

$G$ is a group of permutations on a set $X$. That is, $G \subseteq Sym(X)$.

Function application and composition are denoted as simple juxtaposition and associate from left to right, rather than the more modern right to left. For example, $xg$ denotes the image of $x \in X$ under the permutation $g \in G$. This is the author's notation for what we now typically write as $g(x)$. Similarly, $gf$ the composition of the permutation $f$ with the permutation $g$. In other words, it is $f \circ g$.

### Definitions

**Centralizer**

> For $X \subseteq G$...define $C_G(X) = \{g \in G : xg = gx, \forall x \in X\}$.

**Group Action**

> Let $Y$ be a subset of $X$. $G$ is said to *act* on $Y$ if $Y$ is a union of orbits of $G$. Notice $G$ acts on $Y$ precisely when $yg \in Y$ for each $y \in Y$, and each $g \in G$.

**Pointwise stabilizer**

> $G_Y = \left\{g \in G : yg = y, \forall y \in Y\right\}$

### Discussion

A large part of my confusion here is that $C_G(X)$ is defined for a subset of the group $G$ whereas $G_Y$ is defined for a set which does not have a subset relationship with $G$. I take the phrase "when $X$ possesses a group structure preserved by $G$" to mean that the permutations of $G$ are homomorphisms of the group $X$. Is this correct? Does this allow us to think of $X$ as a subset of $G$ in some manner?

Comment: You said that $G \subset \text{Sym}(X)$ and defined $xg$, as the permutation of $x$ by $g$, but what about $gx$? How do you define this?

Comment: @Stefan4024 $gx$ is not defined. It would seem nonsensical to me in this context since $g$ is a mapping and $x$ is an object from the domain of the mapping. My note about $xg$ is to clarify the odd notation which the author of this book uses. It is equivalent to $g(x)$ in the notation of modern high school algebra.

Comment: As I stated in my answer, the notation seems to be meaningless when $X$ isn't a subgroup of $G$, as if we use the action in the centralizer definition we have that $X$ acts on $G$, which is absurd.

Comment: @Stefan4024 I'm picking this up again after all these years. I think what you say here is correct. $X$ must be a subgroup of $G$. Or more generally homomorphic to a subgroup of $G$ where the homomorphism is actually one of the permutations $g \in G$.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the author by "X possesses a group structure preserved by G" means an action of $G$ that maps $X$ to itself. In other words the group action on $X$ induces and authomorphism on $X$.

A common example of this is when $X$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ and $G$ acts on it by conjugation. And indeed in this example we have that $G_Y = C_G(Y)$. But this relation isn't true when $G$ acts on $X$ by left multiplication.

Comment: If I understand correctly, then my initial thought is correct that "$X$ possesses a group structure preserved by $G$" means that the permutations of $G$ are homomorphisms of the group $X$. (Note that my original question had a typo for this statement.) Is there a more general criteria where we can say $G_Y = C_G(Y)$?